# Passing parameter from local system to gitub repo which is used as npm package in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

Need small help
I wrote a program and uploaded to the github repo. So I can use this repo as a npm package

So I fetch the repo as npm package in my other program

my package.json look like this

```
"dependencies":{
  "admin-server":"github:esrot-server/admin-server#main"
}
```

but the problem is I want to pass one parameter to github repo from my other program so I wrote code like this in my github admin-server

index.js

```
// all the code here
const admin_task =(server_detail) =>{
// all the other code here
}

module.exports = admin_task(server_detail);
```

and in my other repo I am writing the code like this

client-side repo (other program)
index.js

```
const admin_setup = require("admin-server");

// all the code here

const adminFunction = ()=>{
  // all the other code
  admin_setup(adminDetails);
}
```

so When I run the program I am getting `server_detail` is not define but I have define this in my github repo.

I just wanted to know how can I pass my detail from client server to admin server which is in github repo and how can I tackle this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting it wrong. Simply export the function. don't call it:

```
module.exports = admin_task;
```